# Почему может тормозить активити

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При появлении `ImageView` в `xml` разметке активити начинает тормозить. В чем может быть причина? Вот сама разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cameraBG"
android:weightSum="0">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cameraBG"
    android:weightSum="0">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/bgim"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/predPhoto"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutPhoto"
            android:id="@+id/textAboutPhoto"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/aboutPhoto"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textAboutPhoto"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/category"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aboutPhoto"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/textcheck"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoryAnimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkAnimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoryFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoryPeople"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkPeople"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoryTech"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkTech"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoryNature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkNature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categorySelfie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkSelfie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/publicPhoto"
            android:background="@color/btnGrn"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/btnGrnFinish" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Судя по имени bgim там не маленькая картинка.

Comment: Вообще идея в том, что в `ImageView` программно передается путь изображения, который был получен в другом активити через камеру. Т.е. сначала отрывается активити камеры, где после нажатия на кнопку происходит снимок, в последствии чего я получаю путь данного снимка на телефоне и передаю его другому активити, где вставляю в `ImageView`. Первоначально в нем стоит  изображение - это `bgim`. Как я понимаю, лучше всего будет обрезать полученное изображение, чтоб  не пытаться его целиком втиснуть в `ImageView`.

Comment: если у Вас размер ImageView равен 140х140, то картинку большего размера пихать в него не стоит. Пользователь улучшений не заметит, а тормоза ещё как.

Comment: Пришел к выводу, что надо резать

Answer (score 5):

Тормозить может из-за большого размера файла картинки. Попробуйте её уменьшить. Также может помочь назначение картинки в ImageView через к-л либу для скачивания-отображения изображений. Например UIL или Picasso. Я пробовал для этого UIL и она помогала убрать лаги, т.к. присваивает картинку вне UI потока.